# Excel RANDOM formula with percentages for each random number set

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using Excel I am attempting to create a formula using the RAND function but with percentages allocated to each set of random numbers. for example I would like a number between 1.00 and 1.99 to appear 54 percent of the time, a number between 2.00 and 2.99 to appear 13 percent of the time and a number between 3.00 and 100.00 to appear 33 percent of the time. Any help with this? Thank you!

Comment: Kindly also mention the version of excel you are using and you will also have to fix the total number of random numbers in the formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=LET(
    a, VSTACK(RANDARRAY(54, , 1, 1.99), RANDARRAY(13, , 2, 2.99), RANDARRAY(33, , 3, 3.99)),
    b, SORTBY(a, RANDARRAY(100)),
    c, TAKE(b, 1),
    c
)
```

Here is one with a custom function built in to make it easier to adjust the random numbers:

```
=LET(
    r, LAMBDA(count,lo,hi,RANDARRAY(count,,lo,hi)),
    a, VSTACK(r(54,1,1.99),r(13,2,2.99),r(33,3,3.99)),
    b, SORTBY(a, RANDARRAY(100)),
    c, TAKE(b, 1),
    c
)
```

Comment: I like the lambda one. Since the *from..to* values are *+1.99* we could also use this for the lambda: `=LET(r,LAMBDA(x,y,RANDARRAY(x, , y, y+0.99)), TAKE(SORTBY(VSTACK(r(54,1),r(13,2),r(33,3)),RANDARRAY(100)),1))`